# How/where does ServiceStack cache the razor views?

Tags: asp.net, iis, razor, servicestack

When a request is first made to a ServiceStack service, it goes in and looks for all Razor views, compiles and caches them. Where is the assembly cached for the compiled views stored? When in release mode, will updating the views themselves rebuild the cached assembly?

I ask these questions because I'm seeing a very strange issue on my production box. I updated my whole site with changes to a bunch of razor views. But for some really strange reason, my old views are being rendered and I don't see *any* changes to the views.

1. I've rebooted at least a dozen times
2. I've deleted everything (all site files) from the server and redeployed
3. I've updated the views directly on the server to see if any changes can be displayed
4. I've updated the web.config so the app can restart
5. I've changed the Temp ASP.NET folder to C:\Temp
6. I've changed a static image file, to see if IIS is the cause. But no, IIS sees the new image file and sends it down to the browser.
7. I've verified that all my files are correct on the server.

What could be going on? How can the server render old razor views??

I know a lot of this is vague, but any help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The compiled razor views are cached in an in-memory assembly. Touching the web.config to recycle the AppDomain is all that should be needed. I'm not sure why you're seeing old razor views, maybe it's some intermediary caching either on the browser or a reverse proxy cache server.

Comment: +1 for the support and the framework. Can't live without it now. 

Regarding the issue, just got it fixed. Prior to deploying I copied what was there (views,dlls,js/css,etc) into a backup folder. And then deployed and updated the site. What I failed to realize was that the BK folder was in the application folder. When ServiceStack got the first request, it compiled ALL views even the ones in the BK folder (first , i suppose). Hours upon hours wasted on a stupid mistake. Thanks again for your quick response/support.